# What is the meaning of the return value of com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection.insert(Durability arg0, DocumentAssignable... arg1)

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, insert, driver

return value for

```
com.allanbank.mongodb.MongoCollection.insert(Durability arg0, DocumentAssignable... arg1)
```

is **int**.

When I tried printing the return value I got 0. The value was inserted correctly.

**Problem:** It is unclear what meant by the return value 0. So I would like somebody to explain to me the meaning of the return values of the insert function as the docs were not very clear.

What does that int value represent?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the question?

Comment: What does the *documentation* say?

Comment: @pst, "MongoCollection.insert(Durability durability, DocumentAssignable... documents)
Inserts a set of documents into the collection." only that much

Comment: @abhips I think you found a bug. At this point I am not sure if it is in MongoDB or the driver but it appears the 'n' in the result of the inserts are always coming back as zero.

Comment: hi @RobMoore, actually I tried with a simple example and checked the db through mongo shell. Though I inserted the values correctly the return value was 0.

Comment: hi @RobMoore, It would have been a nice thing if you can provide some basic code examples for java-async-driver (assuming that you are guy behind the driver). As I found so many good example out there for the 10gen driver and not many for async-driver. Sorry for asking here as I didn't find any way to contact you

Comment: NP - You can get my direct email address on the Website: http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/team-list.html.  We are adding documentation as fast as we can write it.  If there are specific use cases you would like seen covered drop me a email describing the situation.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [docs](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/com/allanbank/mongodb/MongoCollection.html#insert%28com.allanbank.mongodb.Durability,%20com.allanbank.mongodb.bson.DocumentAssignable...%29) say

> The number of documents inserted. If the durability is NONE then this
>   value will be -1.

So the return value `0` means, the number of documents inserted were `0`(none).

Comment: Actually - The documentation is wrong.  The MongoDB server always returns zero on an insert for the 'n' field which is supposed to be the number of documents affected.  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4381